# How to get current time/position of a SVG animation?

Tags: javascript, svg

Suppose I'm making an animation in SVG like this:

```
    <animate begin="click" attributeName="opacity"
     from="1" to="0.5"
     dur="5s" fill="freeze" />
```

If I use this together with Javascript event handlers, is there a way to get the current time/position of this animation so I can say if it's about to end? I'm looking for something similar to using elem.getAttribute().

Note: my intention is to reverse the animation without CSS support, but anyway the question is interesting by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outer SVG element has a [getCurrentTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/SVGSVGElement) method that can be used to find how far along the animation timeline you are.

Once you know that you can work out how far along your animation is from the attributes it has and whether it's about to end.

There is also an end that's sent when an animation ends which you can use if you want. E.g. `elem.setAttribute("onend", "alert('done')");`

I'm not sure whether webkit supports begin/end events yet but Firefox does.

Comment: This is horrible, but it seems to work. SVG looks pretty limited so far to do controls and animations.